# Parsing adjacent items in Scrapy

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping, scrapy

Still a bit new to Scrapy and Python so hoping for some guidance. Right now I'm trying to solve this using the default lxml, but I've heard BeautifulSoup is good too. Open to trying other selectors if they make this easier.

I'm trying to scrape an html object which has some pretty bad structures. The details of the object are not nested within the same structure as it's name (no divs or anything). I don't know how to extract a node, then extract details from the adjacent node (rather than from nested elements)

Its currently defined like this:

```
<!--first item-->
<h2 class="name">
    <a href="link">Name goes here</a>
</h2>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <td><a href="link">123456</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <td>More details here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <td>1/1/13</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<!-- end first item -->

<hr>

<!--second item-->
<h2 class="name">
   <a href="link">Name goes here</a>
</h2>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <td><a href="link">123456</a></td>
....
```

Notice how the ID, description, and date, are not nested within the same div as the name. Also that the 2nd item is adjacent to the 1st item's name, and details.

Any help on this appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `following-sibling`. As in:

```
hxs.select("//th[text()='ID']/following-sibling::td[1]/a/@href")
```